# Does jetpack compose use drawable-night folder?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

We have a View based Android app with some drawables in `res/drawable` folder, and their counterpart for night mode in `res/drawable-night` folder

When using legacy views, referencing a drawable `R.drawable.foo` from a XML layout file, the system would pick the drawable from either `res/drawable` or `res/drawable-night` folders depending on whether we are in day or night mode.

When using jetpack compose, we reference the drawable in an Image composable like this:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(R.drawable.foo))
```

However, this always pick the drawable from `res/drawable` folder, ignoring day / night mode.

We could do something like this to select the right drawable, but we would need to test the night mode (`isSystemInDarkTheme()`) within all composables that uses drawables depending on nigh mode:

```
Image(painter = painterResource(id = if (isSystemInDarkTheme()) R.drawable.foo_dark else R.drawable.foo_light))
```

Is there a way in compose to ensure that the drawable from day or night mode are picked correctly, and transpartently, as in legacy view system?

Answer (score 8):

Maybe Compose was updated since the other answers were posted, but I can confirm that in a simple app using only Compose and two drawables with the same name in `drawable` and `drawable-night` folders, the app is picking up the dark one, if the phone is set to dark mode.

That's also without a composable theme defined, so this simple code does the job:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Preview(uiMode = UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Composable
fun ImagePreview() {
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_icon),
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Note that you can also see this in a Preview - having two `@Preview` annotations produces two previews in Android Studio, and specifying that you want to see your composable in dark mode is also possible!

[image: dark and light images in compose preview]

Answer (score 0):

Seeing how the dark & light palette is currently implemented in the [theming codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-theming#3) I'd go with creating my own somewhat similar abstraction:

```
class LightDrawables: Drawables

class DarkDrawables: Drawables

fun getDrawable(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), @DrawableRes drawableRes: Int) = if(darkTheme) DarkDrawables.xy else LightDrawables.xy
```

Answer (score 0):

As of now, **"NO"**.

### How to use `/drawable-night`?

`Google` provided support for some basic compose utils through [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/) which does not come with standard Jetpack Compose. For example, PagerLayout, Swipe Refresh and [many more](https://google.github.io/accompanist/).

One of those utils is [Drawable Painter](https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/) and that is something you can use.

After you [add dependency](https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/#download), you can use this util using:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DrawDrawable() {
    val drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(LocalContext.current, R.drawable.foo)

    Image(
        painter = rememberDrawablePainter(drawable = drawable),
        contentDescription = "content description",
    )
}
```

[Document Source](https://google.github.io/accompanist/drawablepainter/#usage)

Note:
*Don't expect dark variant of the drawable to show up in **@Preview**. But it will be loaded at runtime.*

Comment: Does not work for me