# How to load the Dark drawable resource in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I want to load different resource files according to Dark/Light theme in Jetpack Compose, but it is not working.

What should I do next?

```kotlin
Image(
    modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_daynight),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

res/drawable/ic_daynight.xml:

[image: drawable ic_daynight]

res/drawable-night/ic_daynight.xml:

[image: drawable-night ic_daynight]

Res folder:

[image: drawable image]

theme.xml:

[image: theme.xml]

Comment: Your code should work there is nothing wrong with that ... Are you sure you are using different resources ?

Comment: This should work out of the box as long as you're creating your `Theme` correctly and your `themes.xml` is correct. Can you share what those look like in your project?

Comment: Thanks for answering me, I edited the question and added a screenshot of `theme.xml`

Comment: Please post the content of both `ic_daynight.xml`

Comment: I edited the content

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible in the way you've described - see my answer to a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70397756/7707818).

Maybe the difference here is that you're using an old Compose version? Make sure you're using [version 1.0.1 or above](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose#versions) for this to work as you expect. I assume you want this to take effect when you set your device in dark mode.